# Inserting Formula in Formula Bar

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Anyone knows what's the problem with my code?

```
Sub reFormat()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Admin")
    ws.Range("C21").Formula = "=""S4&""AA5&""AA6&""AA7&""AA8&""AA9&""AA10" 'returns applica-
    tion defined or object-defined error
End Sub
```

And I want the output of this code to be: `=S4&(AA5&AA6&AA7&AA8&AA9&AA10)`
Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you go to the *immediate pane* and do `?"=""S4&""AA5&""AA6&""AA7&""AA8&""AA9&""AA10"`, does it output a valid formula? You're probably just missing a closing quote - although, I doubt you actually intend to be concatenating cell *addresses*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, it has a valid output. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: no, it's not valid output. By "valid output" I meant, *something you can legally paste into the formula bar*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh yeah! I've just noticed it just earlier. I will update my question and my preferred output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is fundamentally invalid. The string evaluates to this:

```
="S4&"AA5&"AA6&"AA7&"AA8&"AA9&"AA10
```

Which isn't a valid Excel formula.

You have too many quotes. If these are cell references and your formula intends to concatenate them, and you want your string to evaluate to this:

> ```
> =S4&(AA5&AA6&AA7&AA8&AA9&AA10)
> ```

Then you could just do this:

```
.Formula = "=S4&(AA5&AA6&AA7&AA8&AA9&AA10)"
```